# Auto scrolling with CSS

Tags: css, animation, scroll

In my website [based on wordpress] , I have a project slider (technically image with some text) . But that slider is not auto scrolling , there is a button for sliding left and right .

http://i47.tinypic.com/97uxz4.jpg

I want to remove that button and make it sliding auto . I don't want use any javascript . I want to accomplish with CSS . Is it possible if yes then how ?

If it is not possible what is the shortest possible solution to do this , 
Here is my working site

http://aniyanetworks.net/Blog

Comment: You maybe can use `animations`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: If you don't want any user controls at all, CSS3 animations could work *in modern browsers*. I'm not sure what's wrong with JavaScript, though.

Comment: @isherwood to be honest , I am not good with JS :(

Comment: Time to change that. :-) jQuery makes it very intuitive, relatively speaking.

Comment: @isherwood: offtopic:I know the very basic of JS , now If i learn jquery , can I avoid JS ?

Comment: Mostly. Purists would tell you to learn JS for your own benefit, but you won't need much.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1.) You can't initiate DOM actions with CSS or pure HTML. You always need a manipulating language (like JavaScript)

2.) You can remove the buttons by overwriting the current CSS and adjust the `visibility` or `display` tag to render them away or (placeholding) invisible.

In the end you really need JavaScript for this to trigger dynamic hiding and to make the automatic slide happen with `setInterval`s.

***Edit:***

This might be something for you to work with animating the slider:

```css
#container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

#box {
  background: orange;
  height: 180px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px -400px;
  -webkit-animation-name: move;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: right;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

#box:hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
  0% {
    margin-left: -400px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 800px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HTML</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main2.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="box">as</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Result**

This is the WebKit-only version. These are the equivalents for other browsers:

The `@` keyframes:

```
@-moz-keyframes move {
@-o-keyframes move {
@keyframes move {
```

Inside `#box` (only one property shown as example):

```
-moz-animation-name: move;
-o-animation-name: move;
animation-name: move;
```

Comment: One more thing , how can I stop animation , on mouseover ?

Comment: @ShuvroShuvro, Set `animation-play-state: paused` on `:hover`. I updated my answer.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell: Actually , I don't know how to thank you . You just saved my day . I don't know how to upvote your answer , may be they won't allow me to vote as I am new :( . 

many many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbg9U/1/)) of using `animations`. You could apply this to your `.post-list`:

```
.post-list {
    animation: slide infinite 3s alternate;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -200px;
  }
}
```

To disable the animation on hover, use:

```
.post-list:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Don't forget the vendor prefixes (`-webkit-...` and so on) like in Allendars answer.

But of course you'll have to play around. This should just be a hint of how it could work.

Comment: That's css3 `animations`. I already postet a link where you can get information in the first comment to your question.

Comment: Your Fiddle is incomplete Linus, please update it to show the reference to the animation at least. For more details please check my answer, it's a working version.

Comment: @Allendar, You meant the code in may answer, right? My fiddle was working already.

Comment: Neutral `animation` doesn't seem to work in Safari. I think I misjudged based on that fact. Code seems to work with the extra pseudo styling :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for auto scroll in both limited and unlimited element width:

```js
/*use this js if your element width is unlimited an you want to scroll in a 
constant speed. else, you dont need this js code*/
var elemWidth = document.getElementById('scroll-element').offsetWidth;
var time = elemWidth/80; /* 80 = scrolling speed (44px/s)*/
document.getElementById('scroll-element').style.cssText = "animation: scroll "+time+"s linear infinite;"
```

```css
.scroll-box{
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px 0;
    background-color: green;
}
.scroll-container{
  width: fit-content;
  direction: rtl; /*if you want to scroll left to right set dir to ltr */
}
#scroll-element{
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scroll{
  0% {
    margin-right: 0%; /*if you want to scroll left to right set margin-left*/
    
  }
  100%{
    margin-right: 100%;/*if you want to scroll left to right set margin-left*/
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>HTML</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="main2.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="scroll-box">
       <div class="scroll-container">
        <span id="scroll-element">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
        </span>
       </div>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```