# js/jquery smooth scrolling all the timw

Tags: javascript, scroll, smoothing

I'm looking for a simple way to add a smooth scrolling on my website. All tutorials and plugins which I found are limited for scrolling after calling an ID of the div, but I want to tcroll smoothly all the time, not only by navigating on menu. Waiting for reply and thanks for help. :)

Comment: It may be possible to do it with only CSS, here is some more information : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15485694/auto-scrolling-with-css  Best of luck.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Scrolling smooth when? During what action / event?